# Url.Action does not use desired route for output

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have the following route definitions in my MVC3 website:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "FB", // Route name
                "fb/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            ).RouteHandler = new RH();

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

My custom "RH" handler's code is

```
public class RH : MvcRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            //here I store somewhere that 'fb' prefix is used, so logic is different in some places
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve, that when my website is accessed with the 'fb' subpath-prefix, then my website-logic executes a little bit different way.

The problem is, that when I access my site normally (eg. http://localhost), then when I execute

```
Url.Action('action' 'controller')
```

, then the output is "http://localhost/fb/controller/action".

I want to achieve, that when my site was accessed with 'fb' prefixed subpath, then my Url.Action calls output /fb/controller/action path, and if I access the website normally (without 'fb' prefix subpath), then Url.Action calls output /controller/action

The main thing, that /fb/controller/actions have to route to the same controllers/actions as when the site is accessed via /controller/action format.

The 'fb' route is just needed to store some temporary info when 'fb' prefix i used.

Comment: I might have a solution, but I can't answer my own question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I found a solution based on this link ([MVC 3 Routing and Action Links not following expected contextual Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997412/mvc-3-routing-and-action-links-not-following-expected-contextual-route)), new path-placeholder introduced and constraint added.

Maybe it's not good enough, or you know better than this, but seems to work for me:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "FB", // Route name
        "{path}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new { path = "fb" }
).RouteHandler = new RH();

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```